# Zoom all content of a web page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to replicate or trigger the zoom feature of a web browser using Javascript?

Comment: you mean increasing the font-size?

Comment: @Pablo: probably full-scale zoom, of images, elements and everything, the way `Ctrl` + `+` works in most browsers these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In javascript:

```
document.body.style.zoom="300%"
```

Answer (score 4):

the css3 zoom property may help. This may not work accross all browsers.

```
body {
  zoom: 200%;
}
```